# GCC 5.1 warns cancel construct within `parallel for` construct

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

When I use `cancel` directive (since OpenMP 4.0) to break parallel loop within `parallel for` construct, GCC 5.1 warns "'#pragma omp cancel for' inside 'nowait' for construct" for the following snippet.

```
const int N = 10000;

int main()
{
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    #pragma omp cancel for  // <-- here
  }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de5c52da5a16c154

For workaround, when I split to `parallel` + `for` constructs, GCC accepts the code silently.

```
int main()
{
  #pragma omp parallel
  #pragma omp for
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    #pragma omp cancel for
  }
}
```

But I don't know why GCC warns the former case, nevertheless the construct has no 'nowait' clause.
[OpenMP 4.0 API spec](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) also says that `parallel for` is equal to `parallel` + `for` constructs.

> 2.10.1 Parallel Loop Construct
>
> Description
>
> The semantics are identical to explicitly specifying a `parallel` directive immediately followed by a `for` directive.

Is GCC's behavior correct? or something wrong?

Comment: I think GCC should emit a better error message. Intel compiler throws: "error: cancel for must be closely nested in a for region" for this case (which makes a little bit more sense). Although `parallel for` and `parallel` followed by a `for` are similar, a `cancel` construct allows only one clause...methinks the compiler reads the clause followed by a `cancel` and checks what was the enclosing construct, in your first example it is a `parallel for` and not a `for`, hence the compiler throws that error. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: GCC gives a warning, Clang gives no warning, and ICC fails to compile in the first case. All three compilers compile without warning in the second case. Interesting.

Comment: @Sayan, I'm not sure why ICC's error message is any better than GCC's warning.  Intel seems to think the cancel is not inside a for loop which it clearly is.  It seems like this case https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag1159 which the compiler gives the correct error for.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that your code

```
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    #pragma omp cancel for
  }
```

is not equivalent to

```
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
  #pragma omp for
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    #pragma omp cancel for
  }
  } //end of parallel region
```

in the latter case, there would be two barriers: one at the end of the for and one at the end of the parallel region; something equivalent to:

```
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
      #pragma omp for nowait
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          #pragma omp cancel for
      }
      #pragma omp barrier
  } // and here another implicit barrier
```

but I guess that for optimization purpose, the compilter may try to remove the second unecessary barrier and generates:

```
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
      #pragma omp for nowait
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          #pragma omp cancel for
      }
  }
```

which is more 'optimal' but has the drawback to warn about having nowait and cancel mixed.